# playing sprite Instance at the move phase of touch event

Tags: coronasdk

I want to move frames of sprite sheet with the drag event.The sprite Instance must play only when the user drags .If he lifts his hand it must get paused.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
require "sprite"

-- A sprite sheet with a green dude
local sheet = sprite.newSpriteSheet( "greenman.png", 128, 128 )

local spriteSet = sprite.newSpriteSet(sheet, 1, 15)
sprite.add( spriteSet, "man", 1, 15, 200, 0 ) -- play 15 frames every 200 ms

local instance = sprite.newSprite( spriteSet )
instance.x = display.contentWidth / 2
instance.y = display.contentHeight / 2

instance:prepare("man")


local function startDrag( event )
    local t = event.target

    local phase = event.phase

    if "began" == phase then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t )
        t.isFocus = true

        -- Store initial position
        t.x0 = event.x - t.x
        t.y0 = event.y - t.y

    elseif t.isFocus then
        if "moved" == phase then
            t.x = event.x - t.x0
            t.y = event.y - t.y0

            t:play()

        elseif "ended" == phase or "cancelled" == phase then
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            t.isFocus = false

            t:pause()

        end
    end

    -- Stop further propagation of touch event!
    return true
end


instance:addEventListener( "touch", startDrag )
```